# XNA - Approching two objects

Tags: c#, xna

got another Q for you. I got 2 objects with known x and y coords and i would like the second object, to approach the first one until it is 300 px away. How do I do that.

I tried this:

```
double a = this.Position.Y - p.Position.Y;
        double b = p.Position.X - this.Position.X;
        double c = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(a, 2) + Math.Pow(b, 2));
        float rotation = (float)Math.Atan(a / b);
        this.Rotation = rotation;
        if (c < 300) return;
        Position += new Vector2(-(float)Math.Cos(Rotation), -(float)Math.Sin(Rotation)) * Speed;
```

But it didn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the distance comparison:

`bool inRange = (Vector2.Distance(this, p) <= 300);`

This can replace the first 3 lines of your code.
Now just do something like this:

```
if (inRange)
{
    // Move closer.
}
else
{
    // Flank, begin following, spontaneously combust, slap lightly and repeatedly you name it.
}
```

Hope that helps!